# ID пользователя сервисов гугла

Tags: android, google-play, unity3d-android

Разрабатываю мобильную игру, в которой использую гугл плей сервисы, и нужно мне как-то отследить что бы пользователь не смог сбросить либо поменять свои (в данном случае) результаты, я могу отслеживать его по некому ID, в моем случае он равен:

> ID = a_4698960422747******

В меру незнаю скрыл последнии 6 цифр, а так же я могу отслеживать по имени, но имя он может изменить, и все, гугл мне больше ничего не предоставляет, вот я и использую ID, но остаеться два вопроса, можно ли его изменить, и как можно узнать этот ID самому, т.к. я для этого использовал лог игры.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26413589/get-a-user-id-from-google-play-services) за 2016 год на enSO:

> String playerId = Games.Players.getCurrentPlayerId(getApiClient());

Однако, стоит учесть, что гугл чуть ли не каждый год меняет свои API. По поводу смены ID - пользователь не может его сменить, потому что он выдается автоматически любой системой (сайтом, службой).